# Javascript function for checking if number is prime returns undefined when given the number 2

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have 2 versions of a JS function that checks if a number is prime. Both work with the exception of the scenario when given the number 2. The "Unworking function" returns undefined when given the number 2. Can anyone tell me why? It works with any other prime number I give it that is greater than 2.

Working function:

```
function primeCheck(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return num > 1;
}
```

Unworking function:

```
function primeChecker(num) {
  if (num <= 1) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: because never `2 < 2`...

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not returning anything when `num === 2`.

```
if (num <= 1) {
  return false;
}
```

Would be skipped since `2 <= 1` is `false`.

```
for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
```

Would also be skipped because `2 < 2` is also `false`.

You should check if `num === 2` and just return true from the start.

```
if (num === 2) {
  return true;
}

// the rest of your code.
```

Comment: This answers the immediate problem, but for an answer here, i'd expect to talk about the fact, that even after fixing this, the second method doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

When 2 is passed to the first function, the for loop is not executed and execution continues to the return statement. When 2 is passed to the second function, none of the code gets executed so the function returns "the default return value", which is `undefined`. For more info check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Unworking function` isn't working because when when `num = 2` then there is no return type from this function. And also your `else` condition is not at correct logic.

When any number is not divisible by other number except 1 and this number then it is called prime number. So whenever there is not divisor of a number then you can say that that particular number is prime number.

Your correct code should be like this -

```
function primeChecker(num) {
  if (num <= 1) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```